# C pipe the output of N processes together and count the bytes of each output

Tags: c, fork, exec, dup2

My program uses pipes between N processes to execute this result :
Lets say we execute the program in a terminal like this : `./a.out echo bonjour le monde : wc -c`

The output of  `echo bonjour le monde` is piped into `wc -c` the final output is printed onto terminal so `17` and in a .txt file we have this line `1 : 17` since the number of bytes of the first input is 17.

**Sadly after reading the first output it prints it to the screen and blocks intead of giving it to the second process.**

The important part of my code is after line 78 it should do the following:

1.Loop threw each process

2.Fork a Child that dup2 the stdout and execs the process

3.Fork a second Child that reads the output of the process , counts the bytes(this seems to work) and writes it to the next process

Comment: You have posted no code, so it is not clear what line 78 is.  But, it is nearly certain that the parent process failed to close one of the file descriptors after the fork.

Comment: Or perhaps the child didn't close the ends of the pipe after the `dup`.  This error occurs so often that even without seeing any code I would be willing to give 10 to 1 odds that it is the root of the problem.  Make sure you close all unused file descriptors.